# Are multiple simultaneous Perl POE providers permitted?

Tags: perl, network-programming, poe

I'm using POE to build a system that bridges several protocols (HTTP, IRC, XMPP), and I'd like to use POE to drive a single event loop that handles these protocols.  Can I do this safely, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Read [this article](http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook/Combined_Services), it should help you much.
Also here's code example of IRC and HTTP running together:
Just remember, you need setup everything before you run mainloop: `POE::Kernel->run()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use POE;

# Simple HTTP server

use POE::Component::Server::HTTP;

POE::Component::Server::HTTP->new(
  Port           => 32090,
  ContentHandler => {
    '/'      => \&http_handler
  }
);

sub http_handler {
    my ($request, $response) = @_;
    $response->code(RC_OK);
    $response->content("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>");
    return RC_OK;
}

# Dummy IRC bot on #bottest at irc.perl.org

use POE::Component::IRC;

my ($irc) = POE::Component::IRC->spawn();

POE::Session->create(
  inline_states => {
    _start     => \&bot_start,
    irc_001    => \&on_connect,
  },
);

sub bot_start {
  $irc->yield(register => "all");
  my $nick = 'poetest' . $$ % 1000;
  $irc->yield(
    connect => {
      Nick     => $nick,
      Username => 'cookbot',
      Ircname  => 'POE::Component::IRC cookbook bot',
      Server   => 'irc.perl.org',
      Port     => '6667',
    }
  );
}

sub on_connect { $irc->yield(join => '#bottest'); }


# Run main loop

POE::Kernel->run();
```

And you can [broadcast events](http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook/Broadcasting_Events) between your tasks.